# spacy NER does not recognize some numeric texts

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a custom spacy NER model for entities such as amounts, IDs, etc.
Some numeric values could not be found by the model. The texts look fine, numbers look fine, but it does not extract the value. (accuracy for these numeric entities are above %98)

1. An ID number 81249012 could not be found by the model. If the number is changed a little such as 81249013, 81249014, 8124901 the model finds the number.
   So i did a trial to check the probability it fails. Changed the ID number in the text in range (81249012, 90000000) and applied ner prediction. Randomly %0.5 of the numbers could not be found by the model, even the text is totally the same except the ID number.
2. An amount text "7.653,20" could not be found by the model. Like the first case, if i change the amount a little, it could find the amount.
   Some recognized examples:
   "7,653.21", "7.653,2", "7.653,200", "117.653,20", "17.653,20"

What could be the reason for these 2 cases, some numeric values are missed in prediction.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but do you really need a NER for numeric values? Why not use regular expressions or [pattern matching](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) if you prefer to stick to spaCy?

Comment: The overall process consists extracting different ID's, names, descriptions, amounts based on context. There are different types of ID's. It can be a sender or recipient ID. And there are different types of ID's such as accounts, card numbers etc.

Comment: NER relies on a probabilistic model . Numeric IDs are easy to find, so the model is almost always right, but it does miss a small fraction of values. Regexes or patterns would be deterministic.

Comment: Check this [decision tree](https://prodi.gy/prodigy_flowchart_ner-36f76cffd9cb4ef653a21ee78659d366.pdf), especially the [branch that asks rules and expected accuracy > 90%](https://imgur.com/a/slmP5nZ).